# Boundary of the sum of normal random variables

Tags: probability

Give 2 independent normal random variables $X_{1},X_{2} \sim N\left (  0,\sigma ^{2}\right )$

Assume that the probability
$P\left ( \left |X_{i}  \right | < \epsilon _{i}\right )> \xi _{i}$

Could I say that $P\left ( \left | X_{1} \right |+\left | X_{2} \right | < \epsilon_{1}+ \epsilon_{2})>min \{  \xi _{1}, \xi _{2} \right \}$?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Would you want to say $|X_1+X_2|$ rather than $|X_1|+|X_2|$?  Both of them are different.  If it is the latter, you can have a definitive answer!

Comment: I wanna mention the latter because I am dealing with the L1 norm of a vector :D. Thank you very much for your answer.